# Win 10 UWP get appx File

Tags: win-universal-app, appx

maybe I am blind or I don't understand something right. I have created some HelloWorld-App and now I would like to test in on my device directly. (not via Visual Studios' Remote Tools)

So created my app package in VS but selected "No" for "Uploading to Windows Store" since I want to try it out localy.

The build an verification is successful and all but at the end I got a folder ("HelloWorld_1.0.1.0_Test") in the "AppPackages"-Folder. There are a couple of files. .appxbundle, .appxsym (for each architectiure one)

But if I want to install an app via the device manager it requires an .appx file. Where do I get this one?
I googled a lot, but I only found the descriptions for using the Windows Store.

Isn't it possible without it or am I missing something?

Kind Regards
Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which device manager you install it through, but an appxbundle should be the fine. It's a ZIP file which includes several appx files (for several display scales, languages, ...).

But generally, inside the AppPackages folder there should be a folder like "AppName_1.0.0.0_Test". VS creates not only the appxbundle there, but also a Powershell script `Add-AppDevPackage.ps1`. Run it as admin and it installs the app if sideloading is enabled. This should be the easiest option to test apps on other machines without Store submissions.

Comment: omg... feeling quite dumb now. The .appxbundle works perfect. Have been fixed too much on that .appx -.-

I used the default tool that is reachable via http://127.0.0.1:10080/ (when connected via USB)

Thx :)